# How can I use OpenCV with Python 3 on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: opencv, python-3

I have installed OpenCV and and access it with Python 2. However, I'm unable to use OpenCV with Python 3.

It says "Cannot open shared object".

```
ImportError: libQTtest.so.4: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

I have tried `sudo cat /usr/local/lib` and some other commands but I still can't get it to work.

How do I share OpenCV with Python 3 on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+?

I have also tried following the steps at https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/issues/6 and I have
read [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

Comment: How did you install OpenCV and the Python bindings? Did you just use `apt-get install python-opencv`? It'd also be helpful if you could rerun the code and get the exact, full error message you get rather than just the "Cannot open shared object" bit.

Comment: libqtgui.so.4 cant be shared is the error message and also i did it with cmake thing

Comment: Try running `sudo apt install libqtgui4` and then try again, @John. Let me know if you have any luck.

Comment: @JohnConstantine , [see this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/) on installing opencv on stretch for python 2 or 3.

Comment: **What on earth is `sudo cat /usr/local/lib` supposed to accomplish, lol?**  It's *gobbledygook*, kind of like, "I put the car windows in reverse, but the steering wheel still won't open".  Sorry, but you need to go into much more detail about exactly what you've done vis., "I installed..." and exactly when and what errors you are getting if you want someone else to troubleshoot this.

Comment: To clarify why goldilocks is so confused, @John, `cat` should print the contents of the file you give (in this case `/usr/local/lib`), but you've given it a directory, which wouldn't work. It wouldn't have any side effects, so there's no chance it could have fixed your problem. I suspect you saw the command somewhere as a suggested solution, perhaps?

Comment: the error is **ImportError:libQTtest.so.4:cannot open shared object file:no such file or directory**

Comment: Right.  "No such file..." *does not* mean "it says the library isnt shared with it".  It means there is no such thing to share.  My point about the crazy `cat` command is you obviously do not know what you are doing.  That's fine, that's what help is for.  The problem is you seem to believe you understand the problem better than you do, so you are presenting an (incorrect) version of it.  This leads to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479), which is a waste of your and every else's time (witness that's all that's happened so far).

Comment: Anyway, if you seriously want help, go into detail as mentioned in my last comment.  And edit that information into the question, please do not add it in comments.  Once you have done that, leave a simple comment *@goldilocks* and I will have a look. "Detail" includes exactly how you "installed openCV" and used it with python 2. Also note `libQTtest.so.4` might have nothing much to do with openCV.

Answer (score 6):

> It says "Cannot open shared object".
>
> `ImportError:libQTtest.so.4:cannot open shared object file:no such file or directory`

Yes, but it does *not* say this is because "the library isnt shared with it".  What it says is, **"no such file or directory"**.

As far as I can tell, `libQTtest.so.4` is not actually part of openCV, although it is part of a GUI framework upon which openCV may depend.

According to the [Debian package search](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) (Raspbian is more or less Debian with some minor tweaks), this `.so` is part of package `libqt4-test`, which is available in the Debian current stable version, 9 ("stretch"), armhf compilation, so should be in Raspbian.  You can install this with:

```
sudo apt install libqt4-test
```

This may drag in some other dependencies.  Note if you are using a previous version of Raspbian it probably is not available.

Comment: Thank you @goldilocks your command is work form me in : 1. raspberry pi 3 model B 2. python 3 3. opencv 3.4 4. os raspbian stretch 2018-10-09

Comment: This is still working on Raspberry Pi 4 B+ with opencv 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed OpenCV and and access it with Python 2. However, I'm unable to use OpenCV with Python 3.

With **python** (Python 2) you have installed `python-opencv` from the repository which is the Python 2 version. If you try to use it with **python3** this cannot work. You have to install **OpenCV** for the Python 3 version. Just do it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install python3-opencv
```